# Saving PDF from webview print function always produce a 0 size invalid PDF file

Tags: android, android-webview

I have to following sample code which creates a print preview from `WebView`.

```
public class PrintLauncherFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs

        // Create a WebView object specifically for printing
        WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                createWebPrintJob(view);
                mWebView = null;
            }
        });

        String htmlDocument = "<html><body><h1>Test Content</h1><p>Testing, " +
                "testing, testing...</p></body></html>";

        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlDocument, "text/HTML", "UTF-8", null);

        // Keep a reference to WebView object until you pass the PrintDocumentAdapter
        // to the PrintManager
        mWebView = webView;
    }

    private void createWebPrintJob(WebView webView) {

        // Get a PrintManager instance
        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

        String jobName = "demo";

        // Get a print adapter instance
        PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(jobName);

        // Create a print job with name and adapter instance
        PrintJob printJob = printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
                new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());

        // Save the job object for later status checking
        //printJobs.add(printJob);
    }

}
```

Things look good on print preview page

[image]

---

**However, when I try to save a PDF file to Download using the top right button in print preview page, it always produce a 0 size invalid PDF file.**

[image]

---

Does anyone know why and how I can avoid such?

Note, I have already allowed **Files and media permission**

[image]

Comment: A pdf file is no media file.

Comment: https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/41953798/pdfs-downloading-as-0-bytes?hl=en let check it, maybe it related to the file manager app, which was used to save pdf file. Because your code works good.

Answer (score 2):

your code seems to be okay.

It does not work under `LOLLIPOP`

you should use a condition for **LOLLIPOP**

```
     WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
              if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                createWebPrintJob(view);
                mWebView = null;
              }
              else
              {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, “Not available for device below Android LOLLIPOP”,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
                
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at your code and started a test application on my end just to test your code and try to replicate the issue. (Please vote me up and award bounty if this helps you. Thank you.)

> The code worked fine. Find screenshots below. If you are having issues on your end, please consider the following:

- If you are downloading and you have to name the file, please make sure the file has the right extension. You can see on my screenshot that it has  a ".PDF" extension. Usually it should be ".pdf" in small letters but it did not cause any issue on my end though.
- Make sure there is enough storage on the device and the app has permission. I did not do anything with regard to permissions yet it worked.
- Try on other devices. Android can behave funny sometimes.
- Look at my gradle file and the app I tested in case you need to make some configuration changes on your end. [Test Save PDF App On GitHub](https://github.com/kadankyi1/stackoverflow-android-tests)

> This is the download screen

[image]

> This is the file downloaded. You can see the size is 6.32KB

[image]

> This is the opened PDF file I downloaded. It's just fine.

[image]